# Font-size cqw units

Tags: html, css

I have `container: inlinie-size` with `max-width: 500px`. Inside is a paragraph with `font-size: 2cqw`. My understanding is that font size is relative to the width of the container, so font size should stop growing once the container hits `500px`. Instead font-size keeps growing as the browser window is made wider, even though the container stays at 500px width, why is that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .container {
      container: inline-size;      
      max-width: 500px;
      background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);

    }

    p {
      font-size: 2cqw;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Paragraph with font-size:2cqw, inside container with 90% width max-width=500px.</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Related https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_containment/Container_queries reference "To use container queries, you need to declare a containment context on an element" and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties_and_values/Basic_concepts_of_logical_properties_and_values#block_and_inline_dimensions

Comment: Just to clarify on that page read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_containment/Container_queries#shorthand_container_syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example uses the shorthand version `container`. To use this syntax you must specify both a name and a type separated by a slash:

`container: container-name / container-type;`

If you just want to specify the type, use `container-type` instead.

The reason your example doesn't work as expected, is because `inline-size` is assumed to be the container name, and the container type defaults to `normal`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .container {
      container-type: inline-size;      
      max-width: 500px;
      background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);

    }

    p {
      font-size: 2cqw;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Paragraph with font-size:2cqw, inside container with 90% width max-width=500px.</p>
    </div>
</html>
```